# Passenger Standalone Throws Nginx 404

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger

I have a script that starts a passenger standalone server for my rails app on boot. When I run this script from the command line it works as expected. However when its run by `rc.local` or `crontab` it will produce [this](https://imagebin.ca/v/2eYcnwqFR3mk) error. I cant find any record of this for the life of me in any log file. Whats going on here and how can I fix it?

Some Specs:

Digital Ocean Droplet
Ubuntu 15.10: 32bit
Passenger Version: 5.0.27
Rails Version: 4.2.6
Ruby Version: 2.3.0

Once again this is a standalone server, there ***isn't*** a reverse proxy. I'am using iptables to redirect port 80 to the port passenger is on (Which is above 3000).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out I will leave this as answered for anybody else that has the same problem.

### What Went Wrong

When I opened my digital ocean console so I could see the boot, I saw it was running my `bootUp.sh` script and trying to store th `pid` file in `//passenger.PORT.pid` *note the two slashes*. I thought that was pretty werird... As a novice I didn't know that the script in `/path/to/my/script.sh` wouldn't be executed in the directory it sat in. So when I ran the script from the root directory it produced a similar error.

### How I fixed It

Turns out all I had to do was add the line `cd /path/to/script/dir` above the `passenger start` command I had in my script. The `cd` metioned above just put the working directory of the script where it should be because it defaulted somewhere else.

**I hope this helps somebody else who isn't a expert at this kind of thing because it took me a long time to figure this simple mistake out**